# Rust Nickel Hello World tutorial throwing dependency error when run

Tags: rust, nickel

I am learning Rust, and saw a post on [http://reddit.com/r/rust](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/32dhwb/nickel_is_on_cratesio/) yesterday for [Nickel](https://crates.io/crates/nickel).  As a Node.js developer in my free time, I was interested in checking this out.

I downloaded the Rust 1.0.0-beta DMG from http://rust-lang.org.

I followed the [Hello World](http://nickel.rs/getting-started.html) tutorial precisely, and when I execute `cargo run` in my Terminal, I am receiving the following error:

```
Robs-MacBook-Pro:nickel-demo rob$ cargo run
   Compiling nickel-demo v0.0.1 (file:///Users/rob/Workbench/nickel-demo)
src/main.rs:4:1: 4:21 error: an external crate named `nickel` has already been imported into this module [E0259]
src/main.rs:4 extern crate nickel;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `nickel-demo`.
```

The Hello World `main.rs` file for the Nickel Demo looks like this:

```
extern crate nickel;

#[macro_use] extern crate nickel_macros;
extern crate nickel;

use nickel::Nickel;

fn main() {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();

    server.utilize(router! {
        get "**" => |_req, _res| {
            "Hello world!"
        }
    });

    server.listen("127.0.0.1:6767");
}
```

As I was typing this code into my editor, I specifically thought it was weird that I was declaring `extern crate nickel;` twice in the file.  After receiving the error I refactored the code to this:

```
extern crate nickel;

#[macro_use] extern crate nickel_macros;

use nickel::Nickel;

...
```

And I get this error:

```
Robs-MacBook-Pro:nickel-demo rob$ cargo run
   Compiling nickel-demo v0.0.1 (file:///Users/rob/Workbench/nickel-demo)
     Running `target/debug/nickel-demo`
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6767
Ctrl-C to shutdown server
thread '<main>' panicked at 'arithmetic operation overflowed', /Users/rob/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/hyper-0.3.11/src/server/mod.rs:90
An unknown error occurred
```

Comment: I work on the nickel team. I'm sorry you had such a bad first experience. The examples are out of date and I'm trying to get that fixed soon. However, the problem that you ran into seems to be a real bug in either hyper or rust itself I think. I created an issue to track it:

https://github.com/nickel-org/nickel.rs/issues/185

Comment: @Christoph Yay, I helped find a bug! :)  Thanks for following up with me, and for logging the issue.  I look forward to a resolution.  I just checked the Nickel GitHub page as well and it looks like the current build is failing, also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `arithmetic operation overflowed` bug seems to be an upstream issue. It also affects hyper which nickel depends on.

See https://github.com/seanmonstar/num_cpus/issues/2

As a temporary workaround use `cargo build --release` to prevent the checks altogether.

Comment: I think that [PR #24374](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24374) may be related...